ORA-28000 The account is locked for SYS on the physical standby
I changed the SYS password on the primary and copied orapwd into the standby as documented. This approach worked fine for multiple databases, but for one standby, ORA-28000 appeared after a few minutes.
Once this happened, Data Guard transport stopped and latency started to build.
How can I find and eliminate the cause?

Introduction
User accounts are in the Oracle catalog, and are only accessible when the database is open. The password is stored in the catalog and locking behavior is controlled by a profile, also in the catalog. Depending on the user's profile, too many incorrect login attempts will lead to account locking and "ORA-28000 The account is locked".
The SYS account, however, has its password in an external file. Too many incorrect login attempts will also lead to ORA-28000.
In Data Guard, it is improper to change the SYS password directly on standbys. Instead, it is necessary to copy the updated primary orapwd to all standbys.
When an oracle system account is affected by ORA-28000, it usually means that the old password has been left configured somewhere in the environment. Successful troubleshooting requires finding that old password.
Scenario
Our Data Guard network is Oracle 19c RAC primary on ASM on Linux, and RAC or standalone standbys.
I performed the following actions:

Change the SYS password on the primary
asmcmd pwcopy from from primary DB ASM to a file.
asmcmd pwcopy that file into the standby ASM.
In OEM, update the target monitoring configuration password.
Update sqlnet wallets with the new SYS password.
This approach usually goes smoothly and leads to no issues.

Some ORA-28000 standby issues can be resolved simply by copying orapwd, as mentioned in Note "ORA-28000-SYS Account Locked on standby (Doc ID 2683849.1)"
The issue
After copying in orapwd, "ORA-28000 The account is locked" appeared. Data Guard transport and OEM monitoring stopped working.
In our Data Guard network, there are three standbys. Two are working fine, and one standby is affected by this issue. There are other Data Guard networks, and they are not having issues.
Troubleshooting
The following measures were attempted:

Copy in orapwd to ASM again, or make a new orapwd file from the primary and then copy that file in to the standby. That worked for only 5 minutes, and then the account SYS account got locked.

Stop the OEM agent on both RAC nodes. This stopped the problem.

Start the OEM agents and delete the cluster database and instance targets. The problem reappeared.


The Cause
Even after deleting the target from OMS, the agent targets.xml had a rogue entry for the problematic database. The target entry had the old password:
<Property NAME="password" VALUE="{ENC S}{AES-128}57FC02D10C5F59D0F6B8
29F68FF07B6125CA5255BB642C858595" ENCRYPTED="TRUE"/>

Solution

stop the em agent
edit targets.xml. Delete the stray entry.
start the agent
copy in orapwd to the standby ASM one last time.

ORA-28000 clears up, Data Guard transport resumes, and target discovery goes smoothly.
